# How to fix when changing DB from SQLite3 to MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, window-functions

I am creating an app with rails.
When I changed the DB from SQLite3 to MySQL and modified the SQL statement,
I'm stuck with how to write SQL statements, so please teach me.

## want to

I want to modify what I wrote for SQLite for MySQL.

## Table structure

- chosenitems table

| id | session_id | item_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 5 |
| 3 | 1 | 7 |
| 4 | 1 | 4 |
| 5 | 1 | 5 |

- items table

| id | name | image | competition_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | image1 | 1 |
| 2 | b | image2 | 1 |
| 2 | c | image2 | 1 |
| 2 | d | image2 | 1 |
| 2 | e | image5 | 2 |
| 3 | f | image9 | 2 |
| 4 | g | image4 | 2 |
| 5 | h | image5 | 2 |

## Data i want to get

grouping by competition_id, Count the same numbers in item_id,Extract the most common numbers and their numbers.

For example

If competition_id is 1,item_id → 2 ,and the number is 3
If competition_id is 2,item_id → 5 ,and the number is 2
If competition_id is 3,・・・
If competition_id is 4,・・・

## When writing with SQLite (when using SQLite for DB)

app/controllers/competitions_controller.rb

```
winners_in_index =
    "SELECT *
        FROM (
            SELECT
                *,
                RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY competition_id ORDER BY COUNT DESC) AS rank
                FROM (
                    SELECT
                        items.competition_id,
                        items.id,
                        items.image,
                        items.name,
                        count(*) AS count
                    FROM chosenitems INNER JOIN items ON chosenitems.item_id = items.id
                    GROUP BY items.competition_id, items.id
            ) AS t
        ) AS tt
    WHERE rank = 1
    GROUP BY competition_id"
@winners_in_index= ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(winners_in_index).to_ary
```

## I tried

```
winners_in_index =
    "SELECT *
        FROM (
               SET @rank=0,@before_line_count=0;
               SELECT
               CASE WHEN @before_line_count=count THEN @rank
               ELSE @rank:=@rank+1
               END AS rank,
               * ,
               @before_line_count:=count AS count
                FROM (
                    SELECT
                        items.competition_id,
                        items.id,
                        items.image,
                        items.name,
                        count(*) AS count
                    FROM chosenitems INNER JOIN items ON chosenitems.item_id = items.id
                    GROUP BY items.competition_id, items.id
            ) AS t
        ) AS tt
    WHERE rank = 1
    GROUP BY competition_id"
@winners_in_index= ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(winners_in_index).to_ary
```

I get the following error
↓

```
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @rank=0,@before_line_count=0; SELECT CAS' at line 2
```

## environment

macOS BigSur
ruby 2.7.0
Rails 6.1.1
mysql  Ver 8.0.23

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are using MySQL 8, right? Your original query should work there, you just have to replace your aliasas with something else (the two lowercase "rank", not the `RANK()`, as "rank" is a keyword).

Comment: thanks! 
How to replace aliasas?

Comment: SELECT * FROM (SELECT *,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY competition_id ORDER BY COUNT DESC) AS rank FROM (SELECT items.competition_id,items.id,items.image,items.name,count(*) AS count FROM chosenitems INNER JOIN items ON chosenitems.item_id = items.id GROUP BY items.competition_id,items.id) AS t) AS tt WHERE rank = 1 ORDER BY count desc;

Comment: I got an error like thisERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'rank FROM (SELECT items.competition_id,items.id,items.image,items.name,count(*) ' at line 1

Comment: *How to replace aliasas?* You just pick a different name for it. E.g. ") as katahiks_rank_value from" instead of "rank" (same at "where rank = 1"). You cannot use "rank" as an an alias for your column, as rank is a keyword.

Comment: >> You cannot use "rank" as an an alias for your column, as rank is a keyword.
I used rank for aliasa all the time.Now I changed "rank" to "rnk" and it was done.thankyou!